# Use of "As" to mean 'considered to be or thought to be'

Tags: usage, conjunctions

I have read in http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?s=t

**'As' can be used to mean "thought to be or considered to be"**

> *the square as distinct from the rectangle; the
>   church as separate from the state*.

I don't understand how ***as*** has been used to mean **Thought to be or considered to be** in above sentence.
 Could you please make it clear to me?

Comment: just do the substitution,  then tell us what exactly you find puzzling.

Comment: you can so think of this as elision: "the square, *treated as* or *considered as*, etc. dit

Comment: hit wrong button again, sorry. *considered as" etc. distinct from ...

Comment: if you're still puzzled, tell us what your native language is and we can offer better advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom.  It usually means, roughly, "considering those qualities that are ... those of".  So:  "the square, *considering those qualities that are* distinct from *those of* the rectangle", and "the church, *considering those qualities that are* separate from *those of* the state".

(If my response satisfies, do please mark it as accepted)